# How to get rid of ?instance_id=xxx

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using the plugin "All in one event calendar" from time.ly on my wordpress-installation.
How in the name of all holy can I get rid of the parameter ?instance_id=xxx at the end of my events?
My URLs are like this now: https://mysite/event/myeventname/?instance_id=11
I would like https://mysite/event/myeventname/11/

I've tried everything I can think of in `.htaccess` , but I'm all out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

OK! One problem solved! Now the "prettylinks" works!

One problem remains though... My wordpress installation still links to the ugly URL, and it doesnt redirect. How can I manage this?

Added this to `.htaccess` to get the rewrite to work:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^aktivitet/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?ai1ec_event=$1&instance_id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>`